# Unable to see error messages in registration template. Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Good afternoon Community,

I hope you are all well.

I am building my first website and I have the following problem; when I try to create a new user, if the user enters the wrong data the template does not show the error. Any hints?

Template:

```
<form action= "" method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
<p>{{field.label}}{{field}}</p>       
{% endfor %}     
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
```

Views.py:

```
def register_page(request):
form = UserForm
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()            
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_user/')  

context = {'form' : form}
return render(request, 'simple_investing/register.htm', context)
```

Forms.py:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is discussed in the [*rendering fields manually* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), for the fields you should also render `{{ field.errors }}`, and the `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` which deals with errors not specific to one form.

The template thus should look like:

```
<form action= "" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {% for field in form %}
    <p>
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field.label }}
      {{ field }}
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
</form>
```

The section also discusses how to enumerate over the errors, and apply certain styling to these errors.